# Customize xAxis of an ordinal scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphing

I'm using *`d3.js`* to build a stacked bar graph.

**Example to illustrate:**

I'm charting total miles driven per day. So one may drive 20 miles in the morning, 5 during lunch, and 20 again in the evening. I want to stack those 3 values for a single day.

`X` is an ordinal scale that is based on time. The chart is working as expected.

But let's say the chart has 30 days. I'd like to customize the `X` Axis so that each day isn't plotted as "10/27/2012" for example. Instead, I'd like to customize much like a quantitative scale with stuff like `ticks()` and `tickFormat()`.

It appears those methods available via `.axis()` are only available for quantitative scales though, and not ordinal: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat

So how does one go about customizing a time-based `X` Axis with and ordinal scale?

Comment: Did you figure this out...can you explain why you aren't just using a d3.time.scale() for the x-Axis and then formatting with .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d %b")). Why don't you just nest your data along periods of the day: [morning, lunch, evening] and then use d3.layout.stack() to build a stacked graph

Comment: I found a post over on the Google Group that was exactly what I was getting at. Turns out there isn't a quick answer via the D3 API. Instead it'll need to be a custom algorithm/set up. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/d3-js/time$20scale$20ordinal/d3-js/7GsDmnB4kdE/Rt_EfZnH4OIJ